How to play all the audio files automatically using macros in PowerPoint?
I have several audio files in PowerPoint presentation. I want them all to play automatically (not by click). Is there a possibility to do it with vba macros?
This code runs, but nothing changes:
Sub SetAudioToPlayAutomatically()
    Dim sld As slide
    Dim shp As shape
    
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoMedia Then
                If shp.MediaType = ppMediaAudio Then
                    Set oEffect = sld.TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(shp, msoAnimEffectMediaPlay, , msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious)
                    oEffect.MoveTo 1
                End If
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld
    
    MsgBox "All audiofiles set to automatic play.", vbInformation
End Sub

I also tried shp.AnimationSettings.PlaySettings.StartingEffect = ppAnimationStartAutomatically, but there was a compilation error - unknown value ppAnimationStartAutomatically. Thanks in advance!

Try replacing ppMediaAudio with ppMediaTypeSound.
Refer to this Microsoft Document

Shape.MediaType property (PowerPoint)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
